# How to replace <pubdate> RSS FEED

Tags: pubdate

I'm trying to create RSS FEED
This feed does not validate.
From

```
<pubDate><?php echo $topNewest->data['last_update'] ?></pubDate>
```

echo  `<pubDate>2012-10-02 13:00:00</pubDate>`

I want replace element must be an RFC-822 date-time

```
<pubDate>Wed, 02 Oct 2002 13:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DateTime` class in php which has RFC822 built in

```
 $d = new DateTime($topNewest->data['last_update']);
 echo $d->format(DateTime::RFC822);
```

You can change the format if you need, look at php.net/date